# Query data values where keys are different

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am having a little bit logic issue with querying data.

I have table with `key` and `value` columns

`key` has different values and that values stores data in `value`column

Example:

```
**key**               **value**
car_name              Honda
car_color             black
car_name              Audi
car_color             white
....                  .....
....                  .....
```

I am able to select all car names or car colors

```
SELECT DISTINCT(value) as name FROM `cars` WHERE key = 'car_name';
SELECT DISTINCT(value) as color FROM `cars` WHERE key = 'car_color';
```

BUT, how can I combine these two values?

**E.g**

if `car_name = Honda` show only colors that Honda has in DB stored as `car_color` (in example case it would be black)

**Current output**

showing of course all the values under `car_color` (in example case it would be black, white)

Is it possible to combine these two keys/values?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_ and is used together with `SELECT` to return distinct _rows_. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT value as name ...`, to make code clearer.

Comment: No, it's not possible. With this design you can't tell which vehicle has which color. As it is now you have a bunch of cars (Honda, Audi, etc), and a number of colors (white, black etc.)

Comment: you must create a additional column to group your data while inserting. Example: if your inserting your CAR class to the table, inset t with the object name [HONDA_1] as a additional column and try. Otherwise you cannot do it as you expect

Comment: What if each combination of car_name and car_color would have unique id?

Comment: Each object should have its own unique id. Then you store id, key and value.

Comment: I can't create an object unfortunately as data are coming from thirdparty plugin so I am very limited

Comment: You need something like this  : https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3y5pdqa86

Comment: or created a column `identifier` which has values like this: `audi_black`, `audi_green`. And now you can go with this new column

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create the identifier for me even though it would be great option. But I'll try to dig in and see if I can find the way around this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

At least you must have another column to cater your requirement. So i added a column and created table for a simple explanation. But your system need a good structure to archive your target.

We can add the object names into the new column we introduced. honda1 and Audi1 mean your object names. (Example )

If your unable to add a column, definitely this is not the answer for you and your requirement also impossible.

[image: table Structure]

Then you can use the query like below

```
SELECT * FROM key_values WHERE cat IN (
SELECT cat FROM `key_values` WHERE `value` = 'honda') 
AND `key` = 'car_color'
```

**Note: here i added a 'key' and 'value' as column names, but not recommend to do with your live system.**

Comment: This actually brought me somewhere closer! just taking advantage of common id per car instead of creating new column (`cat`), I might work with this!

Comment: @TheGirl  Cat column or what ever the the column must introduce for the grouping/ categorization purpose. then only you can archive the expected target. thanks